# word wrap / line wrap option in Aptana Studio 3 Beta?

Tags: word-wrap, radrails, aptana

I have been searching for an hour and cannot seem to find any information whatsoever about a word wrap / line wrap option in the new Aptana Studio 3 Beta (aka RadRails 3 Beta). I can't find an option for it anywhere in the Preferences. The lack of a line wrap is killing my productivity. Can anyone shed some light on this please? I can't imagine that an open source project as high-profile as Aptana would lack such a generic and necessary option.

Answer (score 18):

In the latest version of Aptana Studio 3, you can enable word wrap from the preferences.  Try going to Preferences > Aptana > Editors and check off "Enable Word Wrap"

Comment: Doesn't work in Aptana3. Right click in the code panel and select `Word wrap`. Credits to @a-sallai

Answer (score 13):

Right click in the code panel and check "Word wrap".
Took me ages to find but it is there!

Comment: this works for me in aptana 3, just right click on the line numbers and you'll see word wrap. this post is old but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a standard feature but you can use a work around outlined on the below links,

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1650-add-word-wrap

http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Installing+a+Studio+plugin#InstallingaStudioplugin-InstallingNonStudioPluginsonEclipse3.5

I sure hope word wrap makes it into the final release b/c it is the only real issue for me using Aptana 3

Comment: Aptana 3.0.2 Officially supports Word wrap ;)